# Laravel:Trying to generate pdf with charts but on generated pdf charts are not showing

Tags: javascript, laravel, pdf, pie-chart, dompdf

I have installed laravel 5.6 and and installed barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package. I have used some jquery chart plugin to show chart on blade file, it's works fine. By using dompdf package , I am trying to shown this piechart on pdf, but chart's are not showing on pdf. How to show charts on pdf, Is there any solution to show charts on streaming/download pdf.?

The chart plugin/library shows the following chart when viewing on blade file:

[image: chart]

What I am trying is to show this chart on streaming/downloaded pdf

Codes are given below:
Controller Code:

```
public function generate_pdf(){

        $data = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];


    //return view('pdf');

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data);
    return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
}
```

pdf.blade.php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Create</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/piechart.js') }}"></script>


    <script>

window.onload = createPieChart;
function createPieChart() {

    var pieChart = new PieChart( "piechart", 
        {
            includeLabels: true, 
            data: [40, 250, 70],
            labels: ["11%", "69.6%", "17.4%"],
            colors: [
                ["#FFDAB9", "#FFDAB9"],
                ["#E6E6FA", "#E6E6FA"],
                ["#E0FFFF", "#E0FFFF"]
            ]
        }
    );

    pieChart.draw();

}
</script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <canvas id="piechart" width="400" height="400">
    </canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to have a lot of problems trying to make dompdf working with external jquery libraries due to incompatibility issues. What you could do is to check up the requirements of dompds in terms of what in the html code it can convert and then examine if the html generated and operated by that jquery plugin meets those requirements. But I'd bet you're going to struggle a lot, because dompdf is quite outdated and never actually supported much of an advanced jquery interference with the html tree.

Comment: OK... Any other solution to convert blade file html with charts and graphs into pdf.. ? or any other laravel package , or any php solution or jquery plugin solution?

Answer (score 1):

#### Classic Problem - No Easy Fix

This is a classic problem. It affects many different tools, not just dompdf. There are at least three issues involved:

- Javascript

A server-side tool can work with generated HTML but does **not** normally run Javascript. It interprets the HTML and CSS as if it were a browser with Javascript disabled, and therefore jQuery and plenty of other Javascript libraries simply don't work, so any graphics produced client-side are impossible to capture.

A client-side tool can run after all Javascript (jQuery or otherwise) has completed. However, there are still other problems...

- SVG (and other graphics)

There are a number of ways to render graphics in a browser. The old-fashioned way is to produce the graphics on the server and download jpg or png images into a browser. However, that does not provide dynamic charts (not easily anyway), detailed mouseover actions, etc. So most sites now use SVG or another client-side system. SVG is supported by all (or nearly all) current browsers, so it has largely replaced the older methods. SVG (and the older methods as well) is NOT easy to capture for rendering into a PDF or other document. As a result, even with client-side systems you will typically end up with "holes" where the graphics would be.

- Resolution

When producing a client-side SVG chart, everything is sized based on your screen resolution. If you do manage to capture that chart together with HTML, the text will be high resolution (because it is text and can be treated as text in a PDF with scalable fonts) but the graphics will be limited to the resolution as originally drawn. That is fine for casual usage but may not produce the quality needed or desired when printing on a high-quality printer. Typical screen resolution is ~ 100dpi, typical printer resolution is ~200dpi - 300dpi (rated much higher, but from a practical standpoint color images render at 200dpi or greater are typically satisfactory except for art-quality photographs).

#### Virtual Browser Image Capture

The best solution I have found so far is to use a **virtual or "headless" browser** to create everything - running Javascript and producing SVG output along with HTML & CSS. Then capture the output as a high-resolution image to insert into your PDF. You can use any **server-side** framework/toolkit/etc. to both do the capture and create the PDF.

There are free open-source packages available. Probably the most popular is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), but I just checked and it is currently archived/not active. I have used it and it worked, but had quite a few issues.

There are also various services available. One I currently use is [URLBox.io](https://urlbox.io/). I have no personal interest in it - just a very satisfied customer. It includes the option (depending on subscription type) for saving images to Amazon S3, or you can capture locally. Most important, for me, is that you can set very high resolution so that captured images really look great. I use it primarily for automated insertion of images of web pages into PDFs.

Comment: OK..fine, are there some other  solutions to convert html page with charts, graphical representations into pdf with proper format as it is in html.?

Comment: PhantomJS was probably the most popular a couple of years ago, however it is now kind of abandoned. I suggest [headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) instead which is basically a headless version of Chrome that is probably going to be supported for as long as Chrome is.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan Everything I have found that actually **works** is based on some sort of virtual/headless browser, whether done locally (on your own server) or via a service (like URLBox.io). I haven't used *headless chrome* but that appears to operate in much the same way. Unfortunately, I have yet to see anything close to a plug-in library (server or client side) that works as an alternative.

Comment: Css2pdf at www.cloudformatter.com has many svg charting samples from javascript libraries.

Comment: @KevinBrown I'm not sure how cloudformatter does it. But if it works then write it up as an answer.

Comment: @KevinBrown along with charts, there's also text, some other things to show on pdf. Actually I want to show html with charts on pdf

Comment: @KevinBrown Well I have tried css2pdf but blank pdf generated, nothing shows on pdf..I don't know what's going wrong ..I can post  a separate question regarding this, can you see that?

Comment: There is a css-2-pdf stackoverflow tag. I am the creator of that software. You can post there if you like. Or go offline to the website and send us email and we can help you debug and get results. However, this is an in-browser request to format PDF, not an HTML-to-PDF conversion with JS libraries processed and all without being in the browser. We scrape the DOM of the browser as processed by all JS and such (including SVG charts) and format that DOM (serialized to XML) in a remote server by converting to XSL FO and using that technology. That may not fit what you are looking for

Comment: I was only commenting on the answer because the @cloudformatter solution was created specifically to address two of the concerns above ... SVG and resolution, neither are an issue. We format SVG on the server native (as vector) and therefore deliver the best results for included SVGs.